# Tailwind text above header

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to learn Tailwind and create a design like the image.

The template has a navbar and two columns (left pink and right with img). For the navbar, I used absolute positioning. But what about h1 and text below?

[image]

How can I vertical align the `h1` and text below? And how can I make the `h1` move to the right and overlap the image?

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/tailwind.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--NAV-->
  <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 absolute w-full">
    <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
      <div class="flex mx-auto">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
          LOGO
        </div>
        <div class="sm:ml-6 sm:flex">
          <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-indigo-500 text-sm font-medium leading-5 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
      Dashboard
     </a>
          <a href="#" class="ml-8 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-transparent text-sm font-medium leading-5 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
      Team
     </a>
          <a href="#" class="ml-8 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-transparent text-sm font-medium leading-5 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
      Projects
     </a>
          <a href="#" class="ml-8 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-transparent text-sm font-medium leading-5 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
      Calendar
     </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden sm:ml-6 sm:flex sm:items-center">
        <a href="#" class="ml-8 inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-transparent text-sm font-medium leading-5 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
     phone number
    </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Header-->
  <div class="flex flex-wrap">
    <!--Left col-->
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 bg-pink-500">
      <div class="items-center">
        <h1 class="w-full text-4xl tracking-tight leading-10 font-extrabold text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl sm:leading-none md:text-6xl text-right my-auto pl-20">
          Flowers delivery<br> in Moscow
        </h1>
        <div class="text-right pl-40">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, placeat, totam. A consectetur, consequuntur enim est, facilis iure minus nisi officiis provident quasi, quis quisquam vel! Fugit itaque nemo veritatis.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Right col-->
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2">
      <div style="max-width: 70%" class="">
        <img src="https://sun9-59.userapi.com/c206720/v206720075/e9982/Ro2mvWfYfNE.jpg" class="py-20" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negative margins and z-index

Here is a working example using your image as a reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="text-gray-900">
      <section class="flex min-h-screen">
        <div class="w-full lg:w-1/2 bg-red-300 min-h-full z-10">
          <header class="flex justify-between px-5">
            <div>logo</div>
            <nav>
              <a href="#" class="mr-5">Main</a>
              <a href="#" class="mr-5">Catalog</a>
              <a href="#" class="mr-5">Contact</a>
              <a href="#" class="mr-5">FAQ</a>
            </nav>
          </header>
          <section class="flex items-center h-full">
            <div class="text-right p-10">
              <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold leading-none -mr-24 mb-10">
                Flowers delivery<br />
                in moscow
              </h1>
              <p class="pl-32 mb-10">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Accusamus sit perspiciatis maiores dolorum consequatur
                obcaecati.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="border-b border-gray-900 pb-2">Learn more</a>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="w-full lg:w-1/2">
          <div class="flex justify-end px-5">
            <a href="tel:01-800-000-000">01-800-000-000</a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              class="max-w-full"
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527061011665-3652c757a4d4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=633&q=80"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-fog-d33c1?file=/index.html

Comment: grate! Big thsnks!